# How to crimp this type of connector?

Tags: keyboard, cable, connector

I have a Microsoft Natural keyboard, which has an almost broken cable. The cable's outer isolation broke right outside the casing. Now I wanted to cut that part of the cable and simply solder the cable to the board (As I thought the cable was attached by soldering already).

However, as I opened the keyboard I saw that there is a connector which looks quite like this one:

[image]

Now I have a few questions. What are connectors like this called. I need the name to buy the right crimp tool. The housing of the connector could be reused, thus I only need the inner metallic parts for crimping. As this would have a very small diameter my question is if this might be the right tool?

[image]

A friend has this crimp tool but it would probably be of no use, as it is only for bigger cables. This one is here:

[image]

Has anyone any experience with this stuff? Or any suggestions of a nice and clean solution without a crimp tool? I'd be happy for any suggestions. If nothing works, I could still solder the cable to the board, but a connector is in my opinion the prettier solution.

Comment: I would solder it before I'd buy a crimping tool I'm likely to never use again, but that's me.

Comment: @Shinrai The tool would be about 18 bucks (I'd buy a cheap one not the one from the post *g*). That is cheaper than a new keyboard and i have missed the tool a few times before. I think it won't be the last time i use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a pretty standard 4 pin polarized molex interconnect.  I do not think one actually crimps the connector, but rather crimps [these](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_234931_-1) contacts to the wires and slides them into the housing.   I agree with Shinrai that it would be easier to splice in, and solder to the exposed wires in the picture.

Comment: I worked with similar connectors before and this is the correct answer! Just be sure to orient the cables correctly before connecting the metal pieces.

Comment: @AndrejaKo thanks for the advise. Be sure, this is not the first time i mess around with cables and hardware. I just used soldering before but this time I'm really considering buying the crimp tool.